# The camera's up, focus and position values after interaction

Tags: xtk

After interacting with the XTK camera in some way -- translation, rotation, zooming -- is there a way to retrieve from the camera the new values of the position, the focus and the up vector?  It looks like the getter and setters are defined in the camera javascript, but the attributes corresponding to these are not updated during the interaction.  The value returned by `camera.position`, for instance, is not updated even following a translation.

Is there either a mechanism that can provide these values, or a way to add an additional watcher to all interactions that modify the camera?

Answer (score 0):

the position, up vector and focus are used to configure the 3d space at first. then, all interactions just modify the created view matrix.

You can query the view matrix like this

```
ren = new X.renderer3D()
console.log(ren.camera.view + "") // prints the view matrix as a string
```

Comment: Ah, thanks -- that makes sense.  Given the view, is there a mechanism of backing out the camera position, focus, and up vector?  Having dug through the source it seems as though it's a modified affine transformation, but the specifics are somewhat elusive.  The idea here is that we're using XTK as input to a camera path which uses a different set of view parameters and trying to tie the two together.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few solutions depending of who does the job.

First : adding a option to the cameras to enable tracking (disabled by default), an option that would update up/position/focus would be easy no ? Since it's just to multiply the previous vector by the transformation matrix at the same moment than we multiply the view matrix by the transformation matrix. But it may bring an additionnal cost in operations. Or we can compute it like in my "Second"

Second : if my memories are good, the transformation matrix T in a base B(O(x,y,z),**i**,**j**,**k**) has a well known-structure no ? Something like this (maybe I forget a transposition) :

```
 i1 j1 k1 u1
 i2 j2 k2 u2
 i3 j3 k3 u3
 0  0  0  1
```

Where :

```
 ([u1,u2,u3])=T(0(x,y,z)) i.e. gives the translation in the base B
 ([i1,i2,i3])=T(**i**)
 ([j1,j2,j3])=T(**j**)
 ([k1,k2,k3])=T(**k**)
```

Then **if you want the 3 angles it is very harsh** (see euler's calculations), but **if you want something else it could be easier**. For example you want the up vector which is the image of the "k" vector of the base B by our transformation T, so it is [j1,j2,j3] no ? Then, you cannot get easy the focus point, but you can easy get the focus vector : it is [k1,k2,k3] ! (actualy maybe it is -1*[k1,k2,k3]). If you look well the LookAt_ method of X.camera3D, it does not give a focus point to webgl but a normalized focus vector : the point position doesn't matter, you just need 1 point on the focus vector, and you can compute it now, no ? It's just a sum of currentposition & currentfocusvector coordinates.

I wish my memories are well and I am not saying total sh*t.

Just one question : there is a setter for the view matrix, so why do you want to store & set up/focus/position instead of directly storing and setting view ?

PS : caution, There could be a scale operator k, so the matrix would be different different, but I don't think there is in xtk.
PS 2 : in bold are vectors. [number,number,number] is a 3D vector shown by his coordinates.

Comment: I forgot : it is also possible to do like with the interactor : add public overloadable functions onRotate, onPan & onZoom, so you only store the transformations and ask xtk to do it at the good time via the protected methods rotate/zoomIn/zoomOut/pan.